# Team Project Set for SVN in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Eclipse users use Team Project Set Files to define a set of Eclipse projects.

Is there a corresponding feature or plugin for IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Gradle doesn't seem to support checkout of GIT dependencies (yet). I found an older forum post that they were planning for that feature, but I don't find any working example.